# How to give default spacing for my header names in gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, checkbox

I have made a windows application made in Visual basic, and i have added a grid view to that. the grid view populates files from different
folders and list in the grid view. The headers of the grid view are:
first a check box, Second:- Drawing Number, Third:- Drawing , Fourth :- Draft path.
So what happens is when-ever there are no files to populate in the gird view, my **check box look awkward**.
I mean its shrinking too much. How can i correct it. Please see the link https://imageshack.com/i/eyCvEr0nj for the snapshot.
My code snippet for check box

```
    public delegate void CheckBoxClickedHandler(bool state);
    public class DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCellEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        bool _bChecked;
        public DataGridViewCheckBoxHeaderCellEventArgs(bool bChecked)
        {
            _bChecked = bChecked;
        }
        public bool Checked
        {
            get { return _bChecked; }
        }
    }

    class DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell : DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell
    {
        Point checkBoxLocation;
        Size checkBoxSize;
        bool _checked = false;
        Point _cellLocation = new Point();
        System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState _cbState =
            System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal;
        public event CheckBoxClickedHandler OnCheckBoxClicked;

        public DatagridViewCheckBoxHeaderCell()
        {
        }

        protected override void Paint(System.Drawing.Graphics graphics,
            System.Drawing.Rectangle clipBounds,
            System.Drawing.Rectangle cellBounds,
            int rowIndex,
            DataGridViewElementStates dataGridViewElementState,
            object value,
            object formattedValue,
            string errorText,
            DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle,
            DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle,
            DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
        {
            base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex,
                dataGridViewElementState, value,
                formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle,
                advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
            Point p = new Point();
            Size s = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(graphics,
            System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal);
            p.X = cellBounds.Location.X +
                (cellBounds.Width / 2) - (s.Width / 2);
            p.Y = cellBounds.Location.Y +
                (cellBounds.Height / 2) - (s.Height / 2);
            _cellLocation = cellBounds.Location;
            checkBoxLocation = p;
            checkBoxSize = s;
            if (_checked)
                _cbState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.
                    CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal;
            else
                _cbState = System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.
                    CheckBoxState.UncheckedNormal;
            CheckBoxRenderer.DrawCheckBox
            (graphics, checkBoxLocation, _cbState);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point p = new Point(e.X + _cellLocation.X, e.Y + _cellLocation.Y);
            if (p.X >= checkBoxLocation.X && p.X <=
                checkBoxLocation.X + checkBoxSize.Width
            && p.Y >= checkBoxLocation.Y && p.Y <=
                checkBoxLocation.Y + checkBoxSize.Height)
            {
                _checked = !_checked;
                if (OnCheckBoxClicked != null)
                {
                    OnCheckBoxClicked(_checked);
                    this.DataGridView.InvalidateCell(this);
                }

            }
            base.OnMouseClick(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to set the style of the columns and it's headers in the designing area .

Comment: how. can u answer it please

Comment: As this is the windows application , you must be knowing the designing view of your application . On the designing view , right click the column or header whatever you want and select properties . I am using VS-2012 and C#

Comment: @TusharRaj i am programatically generating the gridview.. in my applciation

Comment: @Shell  any idea!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Design Time
2. Runtime (Dynamic Column)

---

1. Design Time: Goto DataGridView Properties -> Columns -> Select the Column from left Side->Width
   [image]
2. Runtime: You can set the column width like this.

---

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 50;
```

or

```
dataGridView1.Columns["chkColumn"].Width = 50;
```

or

```
chkColumn.Width = 50;
```

Where `chkColumn` is the name of CheckBox Column.

---

**Found the Issue**

you are using `AutoSizeColumnMode` property and you have set the value to `All Cells`. This property will check the value in cell and sets the column width according to maximum width of cell value. if the value is empty or null then the column width will be decreased to approx 10px. Either you have to set the any value in cell (ie.  [4 space]) or you can change the `AutoSizeColumnMode` property to `None`.

My opinion is to assign the 4 space in the cell that will automatically increase the width of your checkbox column.

Comment: This already i tried....the thing is my check box column is not reponding.. `dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 50;` annd other tow

Comment: @my checkbox.. is some thing wired!!! i don't know. its not responding .. please have a look to my codes for the check box.. i guess i am messing up something.. thats why its not responding..

Comment: Can you give me complete code of Custom DataGridVIew with Custom Checkbox Column?

Comment: I have email you please have a look to the project